# Boolean To Return True or False in Method

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, boolean

Cannot figure out how to code my method, anything I try gives me compile errors. In short I need my method to iterate through my passed down boolean array. Find out if False appears consecutively more or if True appears consecutively more. In the array I provided False appears more consectively, thus it should return false back to main. I'm at a total loss right now any tips?

```
public class booleanTF
{
   public static void main(String [] args)
   {
      boolean[] guess = {false,true,false,false,false,true,true};




   }
   public static boolean longerTF(boolean[] guess)
   {

   int variable = 0;

   for(int x = 0; x < guess.length; x++)
   {
   if(guess[x]




   }
}
```

Comment: Please take the [tour], learn http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and make a [mcve].

Comment: possible [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43509871/boolean-array-passed-to-method-to-return-true-or-false)

Comment: So you aren't going to include the compile errors?

Comment: Since you only are initializing an array in the main method, no much can happen

Answer (score 0):

You can use flags to check if the current element is true or false and what was the previous element of the array.
You can try the following approach. Ask me if you have any doubts

```
public class booleanTF {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    boolean[] guess = { false, true, false, false, false, true, true };

    boolean result = longerTF(guess);
    System.out.println(result);
}

public static boolean longerTF(boolean[] guess) {

    int variable = 0;
    boolean trueFlag = false;
    boolean falseFlag = false;
    int trueCount = 0, falseCount = 0;
    for (int x = 0; x < guess.length; x++) {
        if (guess[x] == true) {
            if (falseFlag == true) {
                trueCount = 0;
            }
            trueFlag = true;
            falseFlag=false;
            trueCount++;
        } else {
            if (trueFlag == true) {
                falseCount = 0;
            }
            falseFlag = true;
            trueFlag=false;
            falseCount++;
        }
    }
    if (trueCount > falseCount) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
        }
    }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Obviously not the most effective way to do this, but:

```
public static boolean longerTF(boolean[] guess) {
    return findMaxSeqLength(guess, true) > findMaxSeqLength(guess, false);
}

private static int findMaxSeqLength(boolean[] array, boolean value) {
    int maxSeqLength = 0;
    int counter = 0;

    for (boolean b : array) {
        counter = (b == value) ? ++counter : 0;
        maxSeqLength = Math.max(maxSeqLength, counter);
    }

    return maxSeqLength;
}
```

Find the longest `true` sequence, find the longest `false` sequence and compare their lengths.

Answer (score -1):

public static void booleanTF(){

```
    boolean[] arr = {true,true,false,false,false};
    int fIndex = 0;
    int fMaxCount = 0;
    int tIndex = 0;
    int tMaxCount = 0;
    for(boolean ar : arr){
        if(ar){
            tIndex++;
            if(tIndex > tMaxCount){
                tMaxCount = tIndex;
            }
            fIndex= 0;

        }else{
            fIndex++;
            if(fIndex > fMaxCount){
                fMaxCount = fIndex;
            }
            tIndex=0;
        }
    }
    if(fMaxCount > tMaxCount){
        System.out.println("False appers more " + fMaxCount);
    }else if (tMaxCount > fMaxCount){
        System.out.println("True appers more " + tMaxCount);
    }else{
        System.out.println("Same Count " + tMaxCount);
    }
}
```